# Customizing GWT DateBox

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, gwt2

I am working on customizing GWT 2.5.1's DateBox.

My requirements are: I cannot allow dates past 31/12/9999, I need the date parsing to be strict, always (that is, I need allow dates only in format DD/MM/YYYY, which is the format used by my MyDatePickerFormat format), I need to retrieve parsing errors and propagate errors up to the editor framework (and display it somewhere along my custom Widget, which implements HasEditorErrors).

This is a list of the classes I have created for that purpose:

```
1. MyDateBox extends DateBox implements ParseEvent.HasParseEventHandlers.
2. MyDatePickerFormat implements Format
3. MyDateBoxEditorDecorator extends Composite implements HasEditorErrors<Date>, HasEnabled, HasValue<Date>,
    IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<Date>>, HasEditorDelegate<Date>
```

In detail:

1.

```
public MyDateBox()
{
    super();
    this.getTextBox().setMaxLength(MyDateBox.MyDatePickerFormat.MAX_DATE_LENGTH);
    final MyDatePickerFormat myPickerFormat = new MyDateBox.MyDatePickerFormat();
    setFormat(myPickerFormat);
    ParseEventHandler handler = new ParseEventHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onParseEvent(ParseEvent event)
        {
            MyDateBox.this.fireEvent(event);
        }
    };
    myPickerFormat.setParseEventHandler(handler);
}
```

2. > Instanciates 1 MyDateBox object.
   >   Takes a ParseEventHandler to propagate parsing issues.
   >   Overrides com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox.Format.parse(DateBox,
   >   String, boolean) to always call
   >   com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parseStrict(String), and caps the
   >   parsed date to 01/01/9999 at most.
   >   At the end of the parse method, it instanciates a ParseEvent and calls the "parent" ParseEventHandler handler method.

3.

```
public MyDateBoxEditorDecorator()
{
    dateBox = new MyDateBox();
    dateBox.addParseErrorHandler(new ParseEventHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onParseEvent(ParseEvent event)
        {
            MyDateBoxEditorDecorator.this.onParseEvent(event);
        }
    });

    initWidget(Binder.BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
    contents.add(dateBox);
}
```

My issues are the following:

> - The event handling seems pretty clumsy to me (an event is instanciated
>     and handled using one handler, which then fires this event at the
>     enclosing Widget level (let's call that widget "w") which is handled
>     by the handlers that were added to w using its 'addParseHandler'
>     method. That final handler calls an instance method on my
>     MyDateBoxEditorDecorator instance. These are many steps, I guess there must be better ways to handle this ? (I am overcomplicating it ?)
> - MyDateBoxEditorDecorator error handling does
>     not integrate well with my editor hierarchy. What happens is that, when the
>     user modifies the date field content (repeatedly...), multiple parsing
>     events are eventually issued. My MyDateBoxEditorDecorator instance
>     (let's call it "myDateBoxEditor") ends up calling its delegate's
>     recordError() multiple times. Then, when I finally call flush() to
>     flush my entire editor hierarchy, myDateBoxEditor's
>     showError(List errors) method gets too many errors as
>     input (all errors since the last call to flush(), I think). What can I
>     do to avoid that ? (would using an additionnal driver with my
>     MyDateBoxEditorDecorator instances and flush it -every time parsing is
>     done- be the right solution for that problem ?)

Thank you.

PS. I don't know much with SO formatting, have done my best (it looks ugly but is readable enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a heads-up: I have fixed the biggest problem (my editor hierarchy problems with error handling). The cause was I used to call getValue() multiple times during a single editor cycle (every time the user modified the field, for instance), this is what caused duplicate errors to be displayed - according to Valueboxeditordecorator source, one is *not* supposed to do this.
As for the other questions, I wish there were elegant solutions but I think this will do.